# Changing the amount of clicks needed to download file javascript

Tags: javascript, download, click

I made a code based on an `excel` sheet, where you need to click in order to reveal the original cel. That works, but now I want to have them download this `excel` sheet when the visitor finishes all 4800(!) cells. So, I wonder if it is possible to have a click download function which only downloads the file when you clicked 4800 times.

This is the `JS` I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".body table tr td").each(function(){
     $(this).addClass('black');
  });
  $(".body table tr td").click(function(){
     $(this).removeClass('black');
  });
});

document.getElementById('download').click();
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way will be to add the specified download link in the DOM, hidden:

```
<a id="downloadLink" href="link" download style="display:none;"> file name </a>
```

Then modify your JS:

```
    var tdClicks = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".body table tr td").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('black');
        });
        $(".body table tr td").click(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('black');
            tdClicks++;
            if(tdClicks >= 4800){
                $("#downloadLink").click();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, sounds logical! However, if I change the click to 3 just to test it, my linked file doesn't download. I'm sure it's linked correctly etc. do you maybe know why this is happening?

Comment: I would suggest you to first test the download link manually by making it visible and cliking on it